# gtk cellrenderer to display a widget

Tags: gtk

I use thé startediting to render a custom widget when the cell is édited in a treeview.This is a fantastic tool to display my widget.

But I want to do the same when the cell is not in éditable mode. For now,more than 10 Years,it seems to be impossible.

Is there a way to display a custom widget in each cells of my treeviewcolumn?

Do I have to wait for gtk v52 or switch back to Windows forms ?

Comment: Please keep your cynical view for you. Blackmail with developers is the worst way of having them listen to you. Please switch back to Windows forms, nobody has put a knife under your throat to choose GTK, and you most likely paid nothing for it.

Comment: But he is right and you are the reason why GTK and so much development communities suck. And no it's still not possible yet as of 2018.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't display a custom widget in each cell of a tree view -- for that you have to create a custom cell renderer. The process is not unlike creating a custom widget, but there are a few more functions you have to implement. See the documentation for `GtkCellRenderer`.